# Moving back from one activity to another with parameter

Tags: android

I am moving from activity A to B, and then under certain situation (without pressing back button) moving back from B to A from outside of `onCreate()` method of B along with a string value which I have to display on a textview on activity A. I am trying to use `finish()` and `super.finish()` methods but they are not working may be I am using them out side of `onCreate()` method of B, so my questions are:

1. how can I move back from B to A from outside of the `onCreate()` method of B?
2. how to pass a parameter while moving back from B to A?
3. how to receive that parameter in A while moving back from B to A?

Below is code I am using to move from A to B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);                    

startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: Check this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: can cannot finish activity B from outside call finish in activity B to return back to activity A

Comment: StartActivityForResult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Activity B` class write:

```
Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.putExtra("param", "value");
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

In `Activity A` class add:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(data != null) {
            String value = data.getStringExtra("param");
        }
    }
}
```

Start an Activity B using startActivityForResult Method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this.getApplicationContext(), B.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2404);
```

Comment: Beautifully explained...+1

Comment: @Ircover value of code at startActivityForResult(intent, 2404) shouldn't be same as in setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)? i am talking about 2404 and RESULT_OK

Comment: Doesn't matter. The code value (now it is 2404) will be placed into `onActivityResult` call as `requestCode` - using this you can find out what activity returns this result.

Comment: Why are you trying to set result from static method? You can't do that without reference to `Activity` object.

Comment: I am still faceing this error while using setResult outside of oncreate() Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setResult(int, Intent) from the type Activity

Comment: @Ircover ok, i got it.

Answer (score 0):

For a tutorial on moving back from one activity to another along with data you can visit this link : http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example